# Telerik DragDrop: Removing drop indicator possible?

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, telerik

since the documentation (and also the sites i found via google search) does not seem to cover this, is there a way to disable the drop indicator (line between listbox items) with the RadDragDropManager?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found two ways to do it thanks to Blend.
If you extract the template for the RadTreeView in blend you'll see

[image: Template]

You can now restyle as you wish.

Or, the other approach is to programatically manipulate a specific instance of the RadTreeView:

```
        var canvas = myTree.Template.FindName("DragBetweenItemsFeedback", myTree) as Canvas;
        if (canvas != null)
        {
            canvas.Children.Clear();
        }
```